# How to make the Chestnut Application Template for Clojure work?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using the [Chestnut Application Template for Clojure](https://github.com/plexus/chestnut) in a project. This project worked fine for a long time, but it stopped suddenly. Now, not even the default template (without changes) works:

```
> lein new chestnut test +re-frame
> cd test
> lein repl
Warning: implicit hook found: lein-environ.plugin/hooks 
Hooks are deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
2019-01-29 17:22:39.556:INFO::main: Logging initialized @4826ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
REPL server launch timed out.
```

That is the same error I get in my project. I am using Leiningen 2.8.3 on Java 1.8.0_201 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Linux Mint 19.1).

If that is an issue with the Chestnut Template, how can I run my project without the template generated code?

Comment: what version chestnut?

Comment: It works on my machine (macOS)...

Comment: `chestnut` is a plugin that lein fetches. I suppose it fetches the latest.

Comment: The command `:repl-options {:timeout 120000}}` makes it work in my machine. Some people have some kind of timeout setup in their ~/.lein/profiles.clj (or a much better machine than mine). But a simple program like this one shouldn't take that long (it used to work fine in my machine).

Comment: @dilvan when you already have one it does not fetch a newer LATEST if I am not mistaken. If you want that you have to clear your local (.m2) repository.

Comment: I deleted the `~/.m2` directory, generated a new `test` project and run it, but got the same thing: `REPL server launch timed out.`.